# ActiveMQ: периодически слетают слушатели

Tags: php, activemq

Доброе время суток!

Стоит activeMQ, в него через python отправляются события. Есть php-слушатель (Stomp).

Периодически наблюдаем одну из следующих картин:

1) по какой-либо причине слетел листенер. Запускаем его опять - ошибка "не удалось установить соединение с сервером". При этом activeMQ живой. Несколько повторов запуска - листенер запускается.

Сам activeMQ не трогали. Т.е. тупо шло несколько запусков подряд слушателя. Ничего больше.

2) по логам - листенер работает (пишет, что прослушивает события), но админка activeMQ показывает, что никаких соединений с нею нет. Соответственно события накапливаются, слушатель их не получает

При этом, если activeMQ остановили, то листенер падает. Т.е. соединение какое-то одностороннее - листенер знает об MQ, а MQ не знает о листенере

---

Пункт 1 (**activeMQ 5.5**) наблюдали когда activeMQ и листенер были на одном и том же сервере.

Пункт 2 (**activeMQ 5.7**) наблюдали когда activeMQ и листенер были на разных серверах. Такой вариант только опробовали, поэтому появляется ли п.1 или нет - пока не ясно.

Пробовал activeMQ 5.6 - тоже были какие-то проблемы.

Соединение с activeMQ - через простой `new Stomp('...')`.

**В чем может быть причина такого странного поведения?**

Comment: > Запускаем его опять - ошибка "не удалось установить соединение с сервером". При этом activeMQ живой.

Проверьте что в это время вообще соединения принимаются. Тупо телнетом, например. Если принимаются — смотреть почему дальше не идет дело, если нет — почему не принимаются. Причины могут быть разные от бага в ActiveMQ до забитой таблицы соединений (nf_conntrack в случае Linux, характерные крики в dmesg прилагаются) на сервере.

Comment: @drdaeman, телнетом подключился, но листенер на PHP подключиться не может.

"Если принимаются — смотреть почему дальше не идет дело" - куда и где смотреть дальше?